# dependency problems: Errors while processing: keyboard-configuration

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, keyboard, dpkg, dependencies

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, GNOME 3.28.2

When I try upgrade it from console, received:

```
~$ sudo apt update
 ...

~$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.178ubuntu2.8) ...
Error loading new keyboard description
/usr/bin/ckbcomp: Can not find file "symbols/layout" in any known directory
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 installed keyboard-configuration package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup-linux:
 console-setup-linux depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.178ubuntu2.8); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on console-setup-linux | console-setup-freebsd | hurd; however:
  Package console-setup-linux is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-freebsd is not installed.
  Package hurd is not installed.
 console-setup depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.178ubuntu2.8); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 keyboard-configuration
 console-setup-linux
 console-setup
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Searching solutions from AskubUntu i found and try couple commands like:

```
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-depends
```

As result i decrease errors to single `Errors while processing: keyboard-configuration`:

```
~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.178ubuntu2.8) ...
Error loading new keyboard description
/usr/bin/ckbcomp: Can not find file "symbols/layout" in any known directory
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 installed keyboard-configuration package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 keyboard-configuration
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to fix this **`keyboard-configuration`** Error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told before, commands:

```
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-depends
```

decreased problem to `keyboard-configuration` error.

Now i do this steps:

1. Run **Input Method** application:

[image: Input Method Application]

2. Select Update <kbd>Yes</kbd> button:

[image]

3. REMOVE Configuration:

[image]

4. Then run **Input Method** application again, click Update <kbd>Yes</kbd> button and now select my previous settings (in my case **ibus**):

[image]

5. Run in command-line: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.